# Как расшифровать AES SHA-256 CBC?

Tags: python, aes

Есть строка которая шифруются с помощью данного алгоритма.

`b'{"merchantID": "XXXXXXXXXXX", "tokenID": "YYYYYY-YYYYYYYYYY-YYYY"}'`

На выходе я вижу payload
`25BE197FB04DAC542243AC124C3799031007417C2E214C833318C469D7D328DB889B36CDAACBB67D6F528911F3B31F7E3E4D44E3016A5A29D179998665FB4B590F42F4FEFA6771B5302AE1C067D9ACE0F8477D11BA82217B9A9F0E4941545161`

В режиме отладки я вижу след. настройки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь методом decrypt раскодировать строку - выдаёт

```
from base64 import b16encode, b16decode
from os import urandom

from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import SHA1
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

from gateway.exceptions import ConfigurationError

class Crypt:
    """AES-256-CBC crypto class"""

    IV_LENGTH = 16
    token = ""
    cert =  ""

    def __init__(self, conf_token, conf_cert):

        def get_repr_fp(cert):
            fingerprint = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(
                    cert, default_backend()).fingerprint(SHA1())
            fingerprint = b16encode(fingerprint).decode()
            return ":".join(str(fingerprint[i:i+2]).upper() for i in range(
                0, len(fingerprint), 2))

        def gen_key(fp):
            token = conf_token
            return ("".join(
                    chr(ord(x) | ord(y))
                    for x, y in zip(fp, token))[:len(token)]).encode()

        try:
            with open(conf_cert, 'rb') as f:
                pub = f.read()
                f.close()
            fingerprint = get_repr_fp(pub)
            encryptkey = gen_key(fingerprint)
        except TypeError as e:
            raise ConfigurationError() from e

        aes = algorithms.AES(encryptkey)
        self.BLOCK_SIZE = aes.block_size
        self.KEY_LENGTH = int(aes.key_size / 8)

        self.__decryptkey = fingerprint[:self.KEY_LENGTH].encode()
        self.__encryptkey = encryptkey

    def __cipher(self, key, iv):
        aes = algorithms.AES(key)
        return Cipher(aes, modes.CBC(iv), backend=default_backend())

    def encryptor(self, iv):
        """Get encryptor context"""
        return self.__cipher(self.__encryptkey, iv).encryptor()

    def decryptor(self, iv):
        return self.__cipher(self.__decryptkey, iv).decryptor()

    def __pad_data(self, data):
        """Add null padding to data"""
        block_bytes = int(self.BLOCK_SIZE / 8)
        data = data + bytes((block_bytes - len(data) % block_bytes))
        return data

    def __unpad_data(self, data):
        """Remove padding from data"""
        return data.decode().strip()

    def encrypt(self, data):
        """Encrypt content"""
        iv = urandom(self.IV_LENGTH)
        encryptor = self.encryptor(iv)
        return b16encode(iv + (encryptor.update(self.__pad_data(
            data)) + encryptor.finalize()))

    def decrypt(self, data):
        """Decrypt content"""
        data = b16decode(data.upper())
        decryptor = self.decryptor(data[:self.IV_LENGTH])
        return self.__unpad_data(
            decryptor.update(data[self.IV_LENGTH:]) + decryptor.finalize())  
c = Crypt(conf_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxx+", conf_cert= "yyyy.pem")
rawtext = "zzzz"
a = rawtext.encode()
z = c.encrypt(a)
print("Encrypted - :",z)
f = c.decrypt(z)
print(f)
```

Comment: Добавьте необходимые импорты в код и собственно вызовы функций, о которых вы пишете (или пометьте их в коде как-то, если они уже там). Чтобы можно было скопировать ваш код и воспроизвести ситуацию.

Comment: Метод `__unpad_data` не должен делать `decode`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов вернул такую строку    `b'\xc7\xabV\x94$\xa1\xd5\xe4N\x1dA\xbd\xae\nM\x0e\x0e\xba\xd9\xf5^}\x04~\x9a/\x18\x97\xd9o\x0e\x07\x1a\xafW\x9d\xb5\xb4\xb4\xbe~\xa7\x806\x1b\x84]\xfe\xe0\x8d0\xdb\xe5\xb9\xb1$\xb5\xec\xfc\x91\x18\xc5\xcd>S\x9d"\xe5\xcc\xa2X\xe19\xaaF\x06\xcd\x92:J'`

Comment: Во первых, контрольную сумму нельзя расшифровать. Из 32-х или 256 байт невозможно восстановить исходные пару мегабайтов. SHA - это контрользная сумма. Во вторых - контрольная сумма не является строкой, она является набором байт, и чаще всего хранится в неизменно виде в классах и т п, потому что кто-то с другой стороны её может попробовать проверить - и ни один байт не должен потеряться/исказится. В третьих, для визуализации конрольной суммы, её преобразуют в hex, или в base64, тогда это можно присвоить в строку или вывести на экран.

Comment: @CrazyElf сделал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AES - симметричный шифр. Это значит, что данные шифруются и расшифровываются **одним и тем же ключом**.
К тому же, "закрытый ключ" Вы формируете как какую-то непонятную строку с двоеточиями.

Comment: Это на какой строке

Comment: @Radzhab С двоеточиями похоже на heх. Это decryptKey

Comment: @Radzhab В симметричных шифрах ключ шифрования и ключ дешифрования должны быть одинаковыми. Поэтому **одиним и тем же**

Comment: @nick_n_a такс, а на какой строке у меня ошибка?